# karate dsl assertion from request to response

Tags: javascript, java, karate

**This is the request**

And request `{ "accountNumber": "00000000000000041477514" , "prodCodeFilter": "Y" , "pageNumber" : 0, "pageSize" : 100 }`

When method Post

**This is the resposne from api**

```
 {
  "accounts": {
    "linkedLEAccount": {
      "accountNumber": "6541245045",
      "bic": "CHASLUY",
      "branchId": "000000055",
      "branchName": "S.A",
      "cbdNumber": "854321",
      "leAccountType": "NEW",
      "status": "DORMANT"
    },
    "migrationWave": "5",
    "searchedLEAccount": {
      "accountNumber": "41477514",
      "bic": "CHASGBXxX",
      "branchId": "000000071",
      "branchName": "LONDON",
      "cbdNumber": "12345678",
      "leAccountType": "OLD",
      "poolAccount": "Y",
      "status": "DORMANT",
      "sweepMasterAccount": "Y"
    },
    "transferDate": 1549429200000
  },
  "pageNumber": 0,
  "pageSize": 100,
  "requestTime": 1545426348945,
  "responseCode": 0,
  "responseMessage": "Success",
  "responseTime": 1545426348949,
  "serviceName": "Legal Entity account for given input account.",
  "timeTaken": 4
}
```

What i am trying to achieve is assertion from my request to response

something like And assert accountNumber(request) == accountNumber(response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should spend more time reading the documentation and examples. But here you go:

```
* def payload = { "accountNumber": "00000000000000041477514" , "prodCodeFilter": "Y" , "pageNumber" : 0, "pageSize" : 100 }
* def response = 
"""
{
   "serviceName":"Legal Entity account for given input account.",
   "requestTime":1545426348945,
   "responseTime":1545426348949,
   "timeTaken":4,
   "responseCode":0,
   "responseMessage":"Success",
   "pageSize":100,
   "pageNumber":0,
   "accounts":{
      "transferDate":1549429200000,
      "migrationWave":"5",
      "searchedLEAccount":{
         "accountNumber":"41477514",
         "cbdNumber":"12345678",
         "bic":"CHASGBXxX",
         "poolAccount":"Y",
         "sweepMasterAccount":"Y",
         "status":"DORMANT",
         "branchId":"000000071",
         "branchName":"LONDON",
         "leAccountType":"OLD"
      },
      "linkedLEAccount":{
         "accountNumber":"6541245045",
         "cbdNumber":"854321",
         "bic":"CHASLUY",
         "status":"DORMANT",
         "branchId":"000000055",
         "branchName":"S.A",
         "leAccountType":"NEW"
      }
   }
}
"""
* match payload.accountNumber contains response.accounts.searchedLEAccount.accountNumber
```